# Simple "Traffic" light script in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, coroutine, light

I have a simple code for changing a colour between red and green every x amount of seconds by activating and deactivating the 2 light game objects for red and green lights. Or that's what it should do, but nothing happens when I run it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TrafficLight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject redLight;
    public GameObject greenLight;

    void Start()
    {
        redLight.SetActive(true);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(switchLight());
    }

    IEnumerator switchLight()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            redLight.SetActive(true);
            greenLight.SetActive(false);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
            redLight.SetActive(false);
            greenLight.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("loop end");

        }
    }
}
```

That's what I have so far, it doesn't show any compiler errors and the debug shows that it does go through the loop and all. I'm new to C# so I don't know if this code is appropriate for what I'm trying to do. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Since you're starting the routine in `Update`, you're starting the coroutine *every frame*. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not start the Coroutine in `Update()`. This will start a bunch of new while loops (since you are using a while loop in the coroutine), and even if you weren't using while loops this would still end up switching the light every frame and create a bunch of problems.

Instead start the coroutine in the `Start()` function. Also, you need to yeild after both switches not just in the middle (otherwise is just un-switches instantly)

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code that worked for anyone else that might need it, might be messy but it works :).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TrafficLight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject redLight;
    public GameObject greenLight;
    
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine (lightSwitch());
    }

    IEnumerator lightSwitch()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            redLight.SetActive(true);
            greenLight.SetActive(false);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
            
            redLight.SetActive(false);
            greenLight.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).